# line break inside cases environment

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, amsmath, cases

I have an equation using a `cases` environment, with one case with a long description text:

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
    \begin{cases}
        1 \text{too long description of the first case,
            not fitting on the page}\\
        0 \text{shorter description}
    \end{cases}
\end{eqnarray*}
```

The text of the first case is cut of, as it is too long for my page width.

How can I let LaTeX split the line? Using a matrix does not seem like a clean solution to me...

Comment: Better [avoid eqnarray](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use `\parbox` with top alignment:

```
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{cases}
        1 & \parbox[t]{.6\textwidth}{too long description of the first case,
            not fitting on the page}\\
        0 & \text{shorter description}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
```

Further, better [avoid the old `eqnarray` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align). Use `align` or another multi-line displayed math environment of `amsmath`. Here, even simply `equation*` or `\[ ... \]` would be sufficient, since it's a single line, and also doesn't need alignment. `cases` within is multi-line, but that doesn't matter for the outer environment.

Comment: thanks, this works well. I changed it to an `align` environment too (there are more lines in the document, I reduced it for asking here)

Comment: I had to use `columnwidth` instead of `textwidth`, but worked great!